# store retrieve IObservable subscription state in Rx

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, persistence, system.reactive

[ *this question is in the realm of [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx)* ]

#### A subscription that needs to continue on application restart

```
int nValuesBeforeOutput = 123;

myStream.Buffer(nValuesBeforeOutput).Subscribe(
    i => Debug.WriteLine("Something Critical on Every 123rd Value"));
```

Now I need to serialize and deserialize the state of this subscription so that **next time the application is started the buffer count does NOT start from zero, but from whatever the buffer count got to before application exit**.

- How could you persist the state of IObservable.Subscribe() in this case and later load it?
- Is there a general solution to saving observer state in Rx?

---

### From Answer to Solution

Based on Paul Betts approach, here's a semi-generalizable implementation that worked in my initial testing

#### Use

```
int nValuesBeforeOutput = 123;

var myRecordableStream = myStream.Record(serializer);
myRecordableStream.Buffer(nValuesBeforeOutput).ClearRecords(serializer).Subscribe(
    i => Debug.WriteLine("Something Critical on Every 123rd Value"));
```

#### Extension methods

```
    private static bool _alreadyRecording;

    public static IObservable<T> Record<T>(this IObservable<T> input,
                                           IRepositor repositor) 
    {
        IObservable<T> output = input;
        List<T> records = null;
        if (repositor.Deserialize(ref records))
        {
            ISubject<T> history = new ReplaySubject<T>();
            records.ForEach(history.OnNext);
            output = input.Merge(history);
        }
        if (!_alreadyRecording)
        {
            _alreadyRecording = true;
            input.Subscribe(i => repositor.SerializeAppend(new List<T> {i}));
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static IObservable<T> ClearRecords<T>(this IObservable<T> input,
                                                 IRepositor repositor)
    {
        input.Subscribe(i => repositor.Clear());
        return input;
    }
```

Notes

- This will not work for storing states that depend on time-intervals between the values produced
- You need a serializer implementation that supports serializing T
- `_alreadyRecording` is needed if you subscribe to `myRecordableStream` more than once
- `_alreadyRecording` is a static boolean, very ugly, and prevents the extension methods from being used in more than one place if needing parallel subscriptions - needs to be re-implemented for future use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general solution for this, and making one would be NonTrivial™. The closest thing you can do is make myStream some sort of replay Observable (i.e. instead of serializing the state, serialize the state of myStream and redo the work to get you back to where you were).